# How do I get the number of input values from a text file in Java SE?

Tags: java, average, mean

I am a first semester Computer Science student learning Python and Java.

Topic: The interpreter pull inputs from a text file and add them all together and then find the mean.

I have the part down fine where the program adds all of them together (I am using the double, x), my issue is that I want to figure out how to have the interpreter count the actual number of x values that exist in the text file. Sure, I can could them together easily myself by counting them and inputting a fixed value for the divisor used to find the mean, but I want the program to do it so if a different amount of x values are in said text file, the program can adapt.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so I may not be as specific with details as some more experienced programmers, but I am eager to learn. I have programmed more complicated programs in Python previously, as that is our primary language (even there the programs are relatively simple when compared to something made by an experienced programmer). Java (as many of you well know) is strongly-typed, and this is my first real program that I am writing in the language.

Below is my code in the NetBeans 8.0.1 IDE:

```
/*
Purpose: Read real numbers from a file and print to the console only those
numbers which are greater than the mean of the numbers in the file.
Author: Brent McDonald
Date: 26 November 2014
Class: CSC 200 - 001W
 */
package homework.pkg23.average;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Homework23Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double MEAN;
        double x;
        double y = 0;
        Scanner inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner (new File ("RawData.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println ("File not found, program aborted:");
            System.exit (1);
        }
        while (inputStream.hasNextDouble ()) {
            x = inputStream.nextDouble ();
            y += x;
            System.out.println (x);
        }
        System.out.println ("This is the sum of all x values: " + y);
```

Comment: Just add an `int` variable (call it something like count) which you increment every time you call `nextDouble()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the number of doubles as you go along, and then work out the mean once you're done scanning the file.

```
int count = 0;
while (inputStream.hasNextDouble ()) {
        count ++;
        x = inputStream.nextDouble ();
        y += x;
        System.out.println (x);
}
// divide y by count for the mean
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `int count` variable, then in your while loop, increment the count.